# Maximum with Lagrange multiplier

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find the maximum of $f(x,y)=(x+y)^4+y^4$ constrained to $x^4+y^4=1$.

Using Lagrange Multiplier I get
$$
(x+y)^3=\lambda x^3
$$
$$
(x+y)^3+y^3=\lambda y^3
$$

But I don't see how to proceed after this.

Do you have some idea on this problem ?

Comment: Is $f(x,y)=x+y^4+y^4=x+2y^4$ right or do you have a typo ?

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the formula.

Comment: Call $\mu$ the cube root of lambda to get that $x+y=\mu x$ and this should do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a simple way to proceed from here, but the basic idea is that you now have three equations -- the two equations you derived and the constraint equation $x^4 + y^4 =1$ -- and three unknowns $x$, $y$, and $\lambda$.  You then combine the three equations to solve for $x$ and $y$.  (And you can also solve for $\lambda$ but that is just gravy.)