# Problem with Lagrangian Multiplier unsolved

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

This question
[Maximum with Lagrange multiplier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1978557/maximum-with-lagrange-multiplier)
 Has no answer and I would be interested in knowing it.

The problem is the following :

You have to find the extremals of the function
$$(x+y)^4+y^4 \mbox{ such that } x^4+y^4=1$$
One way could be to use the Lagrangian multiplier. But i can't solve the system. Any idea?

For now I've found :
$$ 4(x+y)^3+4 a x^3 =0 $$
$$ 4(x+y)^3+4y^3+4 a y^3 =0 $$

Comment: This isn't fun. You can subtract the two equations and then solve for $x^4,y^4$ in terms of $a$. Plugging back into the first equation you got, you can attempt to solve it for $a$, although you'll likely end up with a high degree polynomial in $a$.

Answer (score 1):

By subtracting the two equations you got you end up with:
$$4ax^{3}=4y^{3}+4ay^{3}$$
Dividing both sides by $4$, grouping terms and taking the cubic root you are left with:
$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{1+a}}x$$
Let's now call $k=\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{1+a}}$
By substituting once again in the constraint you get:
$$x^{4}=\frac{1}{1+k^{4}}$$
$$y^{4}=\frac{k^{4}}{1+k^{4}}$$
The initial function becomes:
$$\frac{(k+1)^{4}}{1+k^{4}}+\frac{k^{4}}{1+k^{4}}$$
You can now minimize over $k$ and then compute $a$ from the definition